# Landscape crashes when paused and Portrait doesnt

Tags: android, multithreading, landscape, onpause

Hello all,

I tried to find an answer online for this problem, but i cannot find a way to fix my problem...

So maybe some of you guys know what i can do to solve it.

So i have a game ( surface view and thread that draws on the cavnas and all that gamy stuff ) and everything works fine in portrait mode, but i want my game to be played in landscape mode, so i have changed the mode in the android manifest like so:

`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Which works fine, everything is the same, except when i want to close the activity ( call onPause method ). When i get the error that the app needs to be force closed.

Now some people solved their problem by adding

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
```

To their manifest files, but that doesn't do the trick for me, i still keep getting `NullPointerException`.

Here is the logcat:

```
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.fishtruck/com.example.fishtruck.Start}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2662)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1154)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at com.example.fishtruck.Start.onPause(Start.java:113)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4563)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1197)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
07-24 21:27:12.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5272):     ... 12 more
```

And (not sure if relevant but what the heck ) here is how i call the `onPause` method:

```
view.stopThread();
this.finish(); //this is called in the activity and view = surfaceView
```

And the `stopThread()` method is called like so:

```
 if(thread!=null){
          thread.interrupt();
          thread.setRunning(false);
          isStopped = true;
          thread = null; 
      }
```

Comment: What object do you have on row 113 in Start.java? The object you have there is not initiated correctly (it is null) which makes your app crash. You are probably trying to do something to an object that doesn't exist. I am guessing that it is (if you posted your whole onPause) the object "view" that is null.

Comment: Oh thanks mate, it actuallly makes sence

Comment: I had counter object there. If you want the post the answer, i will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What object do you have on row 113 in Start.java? The object you have there is not initiated correctly (it is null) which makes your app crash.